# Delphi XE7 Android splash screen - background color

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe7

I can see Delphi XE7 comes with splash/startup image support for Android.

However, when I choose to center the image (which looks best) Delphi shows black color around it. I would prefer white since it fits better with the image and color theme of the app. There does no appear to be an opion for background color where you set splash/startup images.

How can I change this color?

Answer (score 10):

If you want fill the black background with the same background color from your image you must use 9patch images. To make 9patch pngs use [NinePatch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) (included in android sdk)

Once you hace the images, add to your project and set up like this:

- splash tile mode: disabled
- splash gravity: center

Then go to project -> deployment:

1. Uncheck splash_image_def.xml (to not deploy)
2. rename your splash_image.png to splash_image_def.9.png

Comment: I tried this out and it works as it should. This answer should be accepted as the answer to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just wanting to change the background color of the splash screen, you can modify two files.  `colors.xml` and `splash_image_def.xml`.  You will find these in the `Android/Debug/`  (or `Android64/Debug/`) folder of your project.  These get recreated each time you deploy your application so you will need to make backup copies of them.

In `Project|Deployment`, untick these items and create new entries for the copies you have made, making sure that you deploy them to the same location.  You will end up with two entries for `Debug` and `Release`.

Edit `colors.xml` and add the new color that you want like so

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <color name="notification_accent_color">#000000</color>
    <color name="logoblue">#0094ff</color>
</resources>
```

Here I've added the logoblue color.  Next edit `splash_image_def.xml` and change `@android:color/black` to `@color/logoblue`.  It should look somewhat like the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:opacity="opaque">
<item android:drawable="@color/logoblue" />
<item>
<bitmap
  android:src="@drawable/splash_image"
  android:antialias="true"
  android:dither="true"
  android:filter="true"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:tileMode="disabled"/>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

There might be a simpler way of doing this, but this is what I've come up with through a bit of trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

There is no background color property of splash images because this is supposed to be a part of the image. There are 4 different possible sizes for Splash Images on Android:

- 426 x 320
- 470 x 320
- 640 x 480
- 960 x 720

So, depending on your supported devices, you should have up to 4 images matching these sizes, with the background color being whatever you wish. Set it up to fill the entire screen, and make sure you're not using transparency. For `Splash Gravity`, select the `fill` option.

Comment: I have filled all the sizes available in XE7 (which do not include all those you lis?) nd Delphi seems to select background images that only fills e.g. vertial center, but with lots of space around op/bottom. I have: 426*320, 470*320, 640*480, 960*720

Comment: Did you base your images off of the images provided by default in the templates?

Comment: I have replaced them with my own images tha have he exact dimentions as defined in project options - application

Comment: I'm also assuming you chose the option to `Fill`? (I don't have an android available to test with)

Comment: I choice center as I do not want the image dimensions skewed. Since "center" is an option, it would make sense if one could choose the background color :)

Comment: You may just be stuck having to either use the fill option or use a black background, until Embarcadero introduces an option to change this color.

Comment: Ahhh, gotta love that random 2-year-later downvote... :-/

Answer (score 0):

to change default black splashscreen, just open
splash_image_def.xml at debug folder,

and change "black" to white if you want change it to white, like this

```
<item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
```

Note : Build it with no change at source code, layout or anything at RAD Studios. Just edit the file xml with notepad, save it, then rebuild.